# не могу подключиться к базе данных mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет не могу понять в чем дело, подключаюсь к базе данных делаю проверку есть ли ошибки при подключенные, ошибок нет, но данные в базе данных не появляются, код ниже:

```
connect.php

 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'sampp');
 if (!$connect) {
     die('Error connect DataBase');
 }

signup.php

  session_start();
  require 'connect.php';


  $full_name        = $_POST['full_name'];
  $login            = $_POST['login'];
  $email            = $_POST['email'];
  $password         = $_POST['password'];
  $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];

  if ($password === $password_confirm) {

      $path = 'uploads/' . time() . $_FILES['avatar']['name'];

      if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp-name'], '../' . $path)); {

          $_SESSION['massage'] = 'Ошибка при загрузке сообщения';
          header('Location: ../register.php');
      }

      $password = md5($password);

      mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `full_name`, `login`, `email`, `password`, `avatar`) VALUES (NULL, '$full_name', '$login', '$email', '$password', '$path')");
      $_SESSION['massage'] = 'Регистрация прошла успешно';
      header('Location: ../authorization');

  } else {
      $_SESSION['massage'] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
      header('Location: ../register.php');
  }
```

Comment: В массиве FILES нет ключа `tmp-name`. Есть `tmp_name`.

Comment: заменил но ничего так же нету

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: ошибок нету, я уже сам в шоке

Comment: проверь что до запроса вообще доходит дело

Comment: как ? ??????????

Comment: ну поставь на каждой строке `var_dump(чего-нибудь)`. Также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5

Comment: доходит нигде нету ничего

Comment: Что куда доходит? Как ты это проверяешь вообще?

Comment: через вар дамп, я могу что то не знать я еще не такой силен

Comment: У тебя после `if(move_uploaded_file)` сразу стоит `;`. Смекаешь что это значит?

Comment: нет, объясните если не трудно

Comment: ааа теперь понял

Comment: ничего не происходит

Comment: уже все сделал спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)